# Attempting to use a subquery as an expression, need alternatives / help

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, subquery, expression

SQL Server 2005.

I have a stored procedure which accepts a few parameters that may or may not actually have data passed to them.  So they may come through as an empty string, or they may come through with data.

The data would be a delimited list of IDs... manufacturer ID, catalog ID, etc.  The proc searches through records, and if any of those parameters have data, it's used in the where clause.

FYI:  Split is a function that splits a string (accepts a delimiter) and returns a table.

```
WHERE

...

AND m.Mfg_ID in (CASE WHEN @manufacturerIds <> '' THEN (SELECT * FROM Split(@manufacturerIds, '|')) ELSE (select m.Mfg_Id) END)
```

I get an error of:
"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

What I don't understand is that if I remove the CASE statement, so that I just have this...

```
WHERE

...

AND m.Mfg_ID in (SELECT * FROM Split(@manufacturerIds, '|'))
```

... it runs OK; however, this keeps me from being able to pass an empty string.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `(select m.Mfg_Id)` returns a single row, but `(select * from split(...))` returns multiple rows.  A `case` returns a single value, so it doesn't know what to do with the multiple rows from `Split`.

Instead of a `case` you could union them together:

```
and m.Mfg_ID in 
(
select  *
from    Split(@manufacturerIds, '|')
where   @manufacturerIds <> ''
union all
select  m.Mfg_Id
where   @manufacturerIds = ''
)
```

The bottom half of the `union` only runs when `@manufacturerIds = ''`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT m.Mfg_ID -- , other columns
    FROM dbo.base_table_name AS m
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Split(@ManufacturerIds) AS f
    ON (m.Mfg_id = f.column_name)
    WHERE @manufacturerIds = '' 
    OR f.column_name IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Consider this SET @manufacturerIds = '1|1|'. I think you should use exists instead of join. I imagine it could also speed up the sql since you can check for @manufacturerIds = '' first

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be something to do with the 'SELECT * ' part of the CASE subquery. Try selecting only one column instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to rewrite your "where" clause to something that seems more logical to me. Instead of splitting the text into smaller bits, i compare the text with "LIKE". I assume that would give better performance.

```
DECLARE @t table (Mfg_id VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @manufacturerIds VARCHAR(50)
INSERT @t 
SELECT 'aaa' UNION ALL SELECT 'a' UNION ALL SELECT 'ab' UNION ALL SELECT 'abc'

SET @manufacturerIds = '|' +'aaa|abc|bbb' + '|'

SELECT Mfg_ID matching FROM @t m
WHERE ( @manufacturerIds like '%|' + CAST(m.Mfg_ID AS VARCHAR(20)) + '|%' OR @manufacturerIds = '')
```

Result:

```
matching
----------
aaa
abc
```

If you just want your corrent script corrected here is how you could do it:

```
AND (@manufacturerIds = '' or m.Mfg_ID in (SELECT * FROM Split(@manufacturerIds, '|')))
```

Comment: This can be problematic performance-wise, and in fact will cause errors as currently written (Msg 245), if Mfg_ID is a numeric data type.

Comment: I had declared the variable as varchar, but indeed it would fail if it was numeric which was very likely. Changed the script to allow for numerics. Will the split really be faster ?

Comment: In my tests, yes, but it really depends on (a) length of list when the variable does have variables, (b) content of the table, and (c) how often the list is actually an empty string. See my answer for what I think is a much more straightforward approach.